# Do I enter only the latest (corrected) 1099?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, brokerage

MY brokerage account sent me the first 1099 about 10 days ago, I entered it into my tax software, but did not file my taxes yet. Last night I received a corrected version. Do I just have to enter the latest 1099 and forget about the first one I received?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should enter only the data from the corrected version. Most likely, the entry point into your tax software (where you type in 1099 information to create a 1099 form that will "accompany" your return if the return is filed electronically) has a box marked `Corrected version` or something similar, so *edit* the information already entered into your tax software to reflect the corrected data, check the box marked `Corrected version` and continue from there. Depending on the tax software, you might need to re-answer all the questions that you had answered already with regard to *other* aspects of your tax return, or you might be able to jump to the point where you had left off

Comment: Only thing that concerned me is that my tax software (FreeTaxUsa) does not have a corrected box for 1099s, but it does for W2s.

Comment: As an aside, unless you're expecting a huge refund that you need right away, you may want to wait until closer to the filing deadline, to give the brokerage(s) time to issue more corrected returns. Almost every year, I continue to receive corrected 1099s through March.

Comment: By the way, do you know if the "corrected" box in tax software does anything? I noticed that Free File Fillable Forms does not have a "corrected" box for the W-2.